# constructing an acyclic graph piecewise

Tags: graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would like to construct an acyclic graph.

I need to build this bottom-up, because I can only only construct a sub-graph with limited number of nodes at a time. I can also attach root of such a sub-graph anywhere.

For example, let's assume I want to construct following graph (g). Edges are oriented and always point downwards. Multiple edges are also allowed as it is obvious between G and I (I don't think it will affect the algorithm much).

```
           A 
         / | \
        B  |  D 
        | /   | \  
  g =   C     E  F 
              | /
              G
             / \\
            H   I
```

Let's assume I can create at most 5 nodes at a time. The graph may be constructed in 3 steps.

First, create a sub-graph (g1) with 3 nodes:

```
          G
  g1 =   / \\
        H   I
```

Afterwards, we can greate another subgraph (g2), with g1 attached at the bottom

```
          D           D
          | \         | \
          E  F        E  F
 g2 =     | /    =    | /
          g1          G
                     / \\
                    H   I
```

Finally we can assemble graph (g):

```
           A               A 
         / | \           / | \
        B  |  g2        B  |  D 
        | /             | /   | \  
 g =    C          =    C     E  F 
                              | /
                              G
                             / \\
                            H   I
```

Hopefully, problem is clear from the example. I am trying to put together an algorihm, which for a given DAG and maximum size identifes such parts or concludes there's no solution available. For instance, graph (g) could not be paritioned if maximum size was 2.

Obviously, it would be trivial to solve in a tree.

Is there an alghoritm for this? Does this or similar problem have a name?

Comment: It is by no means clear from the example.  If you can create at most five nodes at a time then you can always create one node at a time, since one is less than five.  Since the graph is a dag, you can toposort it and add nodes and edges in topo order.  I don't see what problem you're actually trying to solve here.

Comment: Is what you're really trying to do to identify *single-vertex cuts*? Also known as "articulation points". That is, those vertices such that, if you remove *any one of them*, then the graph becomes disconnected.  A, D and G are the single-vertex cuts in your example, and you seem to be looking for them.

Comment: I think this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component

Comment: thanks for a super fast response. And yes, thinking about it, identifing single-vertex cuts would be very helpful. Will try googling for it. Regarding your first comment, H-G-I part could be built one vertex at a time, however other parts not. If I constructed F-G-H-I, root would be F and I couldn't construct E-G edge (as I said in my question, I can attach only root somewhere, not the the other nodes)

Comment: Thanks for wikipedia link, I believe it will actually help!